# I have developed am application using PHP7 but on the server there is PHP5 and we cannot upgrade the PHP there

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, yii, yii2

Please help me, I have developed an application using Yii2 Framework which requires PHP5.6 or greater, and while deployment of the application on the test server I have noticed that on the test server we are using PHP5.5, So please tell me what can I do? The test server is running Ubuntu.
(Minimum requirement of Yii2 is PHP5.6 and we are using PHP5.5)

Thank You.

Comment: is it shared server or your dedicated instance ???

Comment: It's AWS EC2 running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a few things...

1) Do you need to have the dev modules from Composer on the test server?  If not do a composer install —no-dev

2) Another switch worth trying on the test server is “--ignore-platform-reqs” I don’t recommend it and even though composer install the files the application might not work.

3) If the above isn’t a fix for you, modify your Composer file to put in the constraints of your environments, change your local environment to match the test server, and re-factor the application if necessary.  I’d do that instead of rewriting a whole app in Yii1.

You might want to edit your question and add the information about your composer.json file.  Do you commit the composer.lock file to source control?

Additionally, not wise for your company to use anything older than PHP 5.6.  And PHP 5.6 will have security support ended in Dec 2018.  http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Answer (score 3):

if I recall correctly, PHP 5.5.X and 5.6.X are not that different. So if you can deploy your application and it runs properly, you should be fine. If you are using composer, it might be harder (or impossible) to spoof your PHP version, though.

My two cents:
You tagged AWS (and therefor probably EC2), so why don't you just update your PHP version? Why don't you run your application on PHP 7.X anyway? It is a great improvement - performance-wise.

Comment: Thank you, I'm an Intern at a company and they told me that we can't upgrade our PHP version so Ither you have to downgrade your code to Yii 1 so Yii can run on PHP 5.5 or search or other alternatives, I'm really confused and don't know what to do.

Comment: That's unfortunate then. Did you check wheather it runs just fine by any chance?

Comment: Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - codeception/base 2.4.5 requires php >=5.6.0 <8.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - codeception/base 2.4.5 requires php >=5.6.0 <8.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for codeception/base 2.4.5 -> satisfiable by codeception/base[2.4.5]. I get this error when I run composer install.

Comment: I thought so. A clean deploy is impossible then. Is getting a second server with a newer version an option?

Comment: There are some dependencies on the database of the existing code, so getting a second server I think it's not possible, My boss now told me to downgrade the code and rewrite using Yii 1 Framework.

Comment: Well, sure. Good luck on that mate.

Answer (score 0):

Read the following PHP documentation linked below, particularly the backward incompatibility changes and deprecated features.  If you use any of those, you need to change your code. If you don't, then you should be fine.  You need to test it.

http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.php